# Ordering a list by an enum

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to order a list by enum please see below:

```
Public Class AnimalsToProcess
Implements ICloneable

       Enum AnimalOrder
        Dog
        Cat
        Horse
        Fish
       End Enum


    Public Property _animalList As List(Of Animal)

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Function Clone() As AnimalsToProcess

    End Function

    Private Function ICloneable_Clone() As Object Implements ICloneable.Clone
        Return Clone()
    End Function

    Public Sub Add(animalToAdd As Animal)
        _animalList.Add(animalToAdd)
    End Sub

    Public Sub GetAnimals() as list(of Animal)
        _animalList() 'this should be an ordered BY AnimalOrder Enum
    End Sub
End Class
```

The Add method is called by the external code by passing a value , eg:

```
animals.add(Fish)  
animals.add(Horse)  
animals.add(Cat)`
```

but when the `GetAnimals` is called it should return a list ordered by the`Enum AnimalOrder`.

hence then list should contain the follwing animals in this order cat,horse,fish

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums use integers internally for each value. If you don't set them explicitly, they're auto-assigned in the order defined in the enum, starting with `0`.

You should be able to cast your String value to your enum and from there to an integer. Something like (untested)..

```
Public Function GetAnimals() as list(of Animal)
    Return _animalList.OrderBy(function(x) Cint(DirectCast(Enum.Parse(GetType(AnimalOrder), x), AnimalOrder)))
End Sub
```

Note that you're referring to the value as type `Animal` but don't have a definition of that in  your Q. If you need to access a property to get the value to match to the Enum, say `AnimalTypeString`...

```
Public Function GetAnimals() as list(of Animal)
    Return _animalList.OrderBy(function(x) Cint(DirectCast(Enum.Parse(GetType(AnimalOrder), x.AnimalTypeString), AnimalOrder)))
End Sub
```

OR If the `AnimalType` property on your animal points directly at the enum value (Which would be sensible) you can skip out the conversion *to* enum...

```
Public Function GetAnimals() as list(of Animal)
    Return _animalList.OrderBy(function(x) Cint(X.AnimalType))
End Sub
```

Comment: I had to use `Cint(DirectCast(Enum.Parse(GetType(AnimalOrder), x.tostring()`   to get it work, Thanks

Comment: You're welcome - glad I could help - but I don't understand why you needed to `ToString()` it? Surely your object has a property which exposes the animal somehow (`MyAnimal.Type` or `MyAnimal.TypeName` or similar?) If it's not an object but just a string, you should be able to use `x` as well as `x.ToString()`